# Windows Server Update Services

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I'm trying to add Windows Server Update Services, but whenever I try to start it to do the post-installation it gives me this error..

I tried adding II_IUSRS, NETWORK, NETWORK SERVICES, SERVICES to **log on as service** for Default Domain Controllers Policy.

I also tried adding it to Default Domain Policy, but nothing seems to be working.

```
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Postinstall started
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Detected role services: Api, UI, WidDatabase, Services
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Start: LoadSettingsFromXml
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Start: GetConfigValue with filename=UpdateServices-Services.xml item=ContentLocal
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Value is true
2021-09-08 12:12:40  End: GetConfigValue
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Start: GetConfigValue with filename=UpdateServices-Services.xml item=ContentDirectory
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Value is D:\WSUS_database
2021-09-08 12:12:40  End: GetConfigValue
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Content directory is D:\WSUS_database
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Database roleservice is not installed
2021-09-08 12:12:40  End: LoadSettingsFromXml
Post install is starting
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Start: Run
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Fetching WsusAdministratorsSid from registry store
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Value is S-1-5-21-2939769649-1620940919
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Fetching WsusReportersSid from registry store
2021-09-08 12:12:40  Value is S-1-5-21-2939769649-1620940919
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Configuring content directory...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Configuring groups...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Starting group configuration for WSUS Administrators...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Found group in regsitry, attempting to use it...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Searching for existing group...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Existing group was found
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Writing group to registry...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Finished group creation
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Starting group configuration for WSUS Reporters...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Found group in regsitry, attempting to use it...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Searching for existing group...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Existing group was found
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Writing group to registry...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Finished group creation
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Configuring permissions...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Fetching content directory...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Fetching ContentDir from registry store
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Value is D:\WSUS_database
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Fetching group SIDs...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Fetching WsusAdministratorsSid from registry store
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Value is S-1-5-21-2939769649-1620940919
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Fetching WsusReportersSid from registry store
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Value is S-1-5-21-2939769649-1620940919
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Creating group principals...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Granting directory permissions...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Granting permissions on content directory...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Granting registry permissions...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Granting registry permissions...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Granting registry permissions...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Configuring shares...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Configuring network shares...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Fetching content directory...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Fetching ContentDir from registry store
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Value is D:\WSUS_database
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Fetching WSUS admin SID...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Fetching WsusAdministratorsSid from registry store
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Value is S-1-5-21-2939769649-1620940919
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Content directory is local, creating content shares...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Creating share "UpdateServicesPackages" with path "D:\WSUS_database\UpdateServicesPackages" and description "A network share to be used by client systems for collecting all software packages (usually applications) published on this WSUS system."
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Deleting existing share...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Creating share...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Share successfully created
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Creating share "WsusContent" with path "D:\WSUS_database\WsusContent" and description "A network share to be used by Local Publishing to place published content on this WSUS system."
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Deleting existing share...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Creating share...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Share successfully created
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Creating share "WSUSTemp" with path "C:\Program Files\Update Services\LogFiles\WSUSTemp" and description "A network share used by Local Publishing from a Remote WSUS Console Instance."
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Deleting existing share...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Creating share...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Share successfully created
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Finished creating content shares
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Stopping service WSUSService
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Stopping service W3SVC
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Configuring WID database...
2021-09-08 12:13:40  Configuring the database...
2021-09-08 12:14:11  System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot start service MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID on computer '.'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ConfigureDB.StartAndConfigWidService()
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ConfigureDB.Configure()
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.ConfigureDB.Run(String instanceName, Action`1 logWriter, Boolean contentLocal)
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.PostInstall.Run()
   at Microsoft.UpdateServices.Administration.PostInstall.Execute(String[] arguments)
Fatal Error: Cannot start service MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID on computer '.'.
```

Answer (score 0):

•   Ensure that .NET Framework 4.7 is not installed for OS versions other than Windows Server 2019 as the OS versions prior to Windows Server 2019 are not compatible to this version of .NET Framework.

•   Try giving ‘Logon as a service’ permission to ‘NT SERVICE\ALL SERVICES’ through group policy and add the service account used to install the WSUS role in ‘IIS_IUSRS’ group on the member server used to install the WSUS role. Don’t forget to exclude the computer from the GPO that defines the user right.

•   Try restarting the server and then in the ‘Services.msc’ section, open the properties of the ‘Windows Internal Database’ service and check the logon tab. In that tab, change it temporarily as ‘local system’ account during the post-installation process completion.

•   At last, if any of the above options doesn’t work for you, try adding the ‘NT SERVICE\MSSQL$MICROSOFT##WID’ account to the ‘Logon as a service’ right in the local security policy of the server and then try the post-installation process once again.

Please refer the below link for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/error-install-windows-internal-database